# Wordpress 6 - Not able to see custom admin menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress 6.1 version and new in developing a Wordpress theme.

So my basic idea is to have an admin menu. Please find the following code below.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    /*
    Theme Name: shopping-theme-wordpress
    Author: wp content
    Author URI: https://wp-content.co/
    Description: My custom theme
    Version: 1.0
    Tested upto: 5.4
    */

    /**
     * Register a custom menu page.
     */
    function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page(){
        add_menu_page( 
            __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'textdomain' ),
            'custom menu',
            'manage_options',
            'custompage',
            'my_custom_menu_page',
            plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ),
            6
        ); 
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page' );

    /**
     * Display a custom menu page
     */
    function my_custom_menu_page(){
        esc_html_e( 'Admin Page Test', 'textdomain' );  
    }

    get_header();
    get_footer();
?>
```

But when I check in the Wordpress dashboard, I am not able to see my custom menu.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**Reference**

1. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you mixed up everything.

First of all, you have to refer this documentation to get an idea about Theme Development: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Because there's a [structure](https://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) you have to follow when developing a theme.

Secondly, in your theme, you would have a `functions.php` file. You can write the hooks there. I mean this portion of code can be written there:

```
/**
 * Register a custom menu page.
 */
function wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 
        __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'textdomain' ),
        'custom menu',
        'manage_options',
        'custompage',
        'my_custom_menu_page',
        plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ),
        6
    ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpdocs_register_my_custom_menu_page' );

/**
 * Display a custom menu page
 */
function my_custom_menu_page(){
    esc_html_e( 'Admin Page Test', 'textdomain' );  
}
```

That `get_header()` and `get_footer()` is supposed to be used only in the [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/). And the details(name of the theme, description, author, etc.) about your theme is supposed to be included in the [style.css file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/).

You need to go through the [theme basics](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/) to get a better idea. Hope it helps.